# How to compile manual files .1

Tags: c, c++, linker

I have .c, .h, and .1 files, how can I compile them together in one executable file. Everything clear with .c and .h files, but I have also .1 as I can see from the content it is used for manual, how can link them with program?

Comment: You don't link man pages with executables. They're shipped separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have also .1 as I can see from the content it is used for manual

Yes, these are written in [groff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_(software)) markup.  They aren't compiled, they're interpreted at runtime via `man` or some other viewer (using `groff` as a backend).

The `.1` actually denotes the manual section (see `man man`).  When an executable  is installed into an element of the system's executable path (e.g., `/usr/bin`), the corresponding man page is also usually installed into a subdirectory of, e.g., `/usr/share/man`.  Often they are compressed as well (so `foobar.1.gz`).

`man` systems maintain a cache and do some indexing of the content (for `apropos`, etc.), but how this is invoked differs between implementations.  Traditionally the update command was `makewhatis`, but the newer mandb system uses `mandb`.  Distros often set this up to run at regular intervals via `cron` rather than do it as part of the install since it can be a little time consuming.

Comment: Thx a lot for help